# AWS Cognito not sending verification email with serverless

Tags: amazon-cognito, serverless

I am trying to create a user sign in with Amplify and Cognito. I can correctly load the user to the user pool but can not verify the user because AWS is not sending me a verification email with the corresponding code.

I think I need to add something else to my yml file.... I am not sure what.

I followed one demo and this is how they set up their yml.

Thanks

Here is my .yml:

```
CognitoUserPool:
  Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
  Properties:
    UserPoolName: cognito_sls_backend_user_pool_2
    AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - email
    MfaConfiguration: "OFF"
    EmailVerificationSubject: "Your Fly Box verification code"
    EmailVerificationMessage: "Your Fly Box verification code is {####}."
    # SmsAuthenticationMessage: "Your Digispeaker authentication code is 
{####}."


    Schema:
      - Name: email
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: false
      - Name: password
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: false
# Cognito - Client
CognitoUserPoolClient:
  Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
  Properties:
    ClientName: cognito_sls_backend_client
    UserPoolId:
      Ref: CognitoUserPool
# Cognito - Identity
CognitoIdentityPool:
  Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool
  Properties:
    IdentityPoolName: cognito_sls_backend_identity_pool
    AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: false
    CognitoIdentityProviders:
      - ClientId:
          Ref: CognitoUserPoolClient
        ProviderName:
          Fn::GetAtt: [CognitoUserPool, ProviderName]
# Cognito roles
CognitoIdentityPoolRoles:
  Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment
  Properties:
    IdentityPoolId:
      Ref: CognitoIdentityPool
    Roles:
      authenticated:
        Fn::GetAtt: [CognitoAuthRole, Arn]
      unauthenticated:
        Fn::GetAtt: [CognitoUnauthRole, Arn]
CognitoAuthRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName: appAuthRole
    Path: /
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Principal:
            Federated: "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud":
                Ref: CognitoIdentityPool
            "ForAnyValue:StringLike":
              "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": authenticated
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: "CognitoAuthorizedPolicy"
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Action:
                - "mobileanalytics:PutEvents"
                - "cognito-sync:*"
                - "cognito-identity:*"
              Resource: "*"
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Action:
                - "execute-api:Invoke"
              Resource: "*"
CognitoUnauthRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName: appUnauthRole
    Path: /
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Principal:
            Federated: "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud":
                Ref: CognitoIdentityPool
            "ForAnyValue:StringLike":
              "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": unauthenticated
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: "CognitoUnauthorizedPolicy"
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Action:
                - "mobileanalytics:PutEvents"
                - "cognito-sync:*"
                - "cognito-identity:*"
              Resource: "*"
```

Comment: How are you creating the user? I had similar issue and it was because I added email next to the username instead into the attributes object.